# How to get S3 directory as os.path in Python with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, keras, boto3

In Python, we usually deal with directories like this:

```
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")
```

But, let's say I have the same logs directory inside an S3 Bucket, how am I supposed to get the path on S3 as `str` using `boto3`?

Use case:

I'm writing a AWS Lambda function which loads weights from an `s3` bucket to a `Keras` model to return the predictions.

Comment: You cannot do this natively but you could mount an S3 bucket as a local file system, see https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/amazon-s3-as-a-file-system. I'm personally not a big fan of these kind of solutions and would prefer to work natively with S3 via SDK or awscli.

Comment: So, you mean using a s3 url like this `s3://` will help, instead of using boto3?

Comment: You can’t access files in S3 as if they were local files without some kind of mountable file system driver like s3fuse. Is that what you’re trying to do, or are you simply trying to work out how to construct an S3 path as a string? If the latter then just construct by concatenating s3:// with the bucket and then the object key e.g. s3://mybucket/cats/fluffykins.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If Keras supports S3 directly then read the Keras documentation and do what it says.

If Keras supports loading model data from memory, then read the file from S3 into memory and load the model data from there. For example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='data/input.csv')
contents = obj['Body'].read()
# model = load_model(contents)
```

If Keras requires a local file, then download the file from S3 to /tmp in Lambda and then load the model data from there. For example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'data/input.csv', '/tmp/input.csv')
# model = load_model('/tmp/input.csv')
```

I suspect the latter is what you need and to load multiple files simply download each file from S3 to /tmp and then load the model from /tmp.

Comment: I want to pass the directory to a model not the file from obj.